# how do I count data that has been recorded by the current user?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

This is the getUserId and my function to count data that required the userId:

```
String get getuserId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;
```

```
Future<AggregateQuerySnapshot> myCollectionPrayer({required String userId}) =>
     FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('record_prayer')
         .where('dailyPrayerStatus', isEqualTo: 'Prayed On Time')
         .count()
         .get();
```

This is where I'm using the `FutureBuilder``<AggregateQuerySnapshot>`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Count Firebase Documents'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder<AggregateQuerySnapshot>(
      future: myCollectionPrayer(userId: getuserId),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('oops');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          int docCount = snapshot.data!.count;
          return Text(
            docCount.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
          );
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
```

There is no error on the code, but the display count for all user recorded data.

this my screenshot for firebase

[image]

Comment: what is AggregateQuerySnapshot in your code, and what does the count() in your method

Comment: However, I can clearly see that the `myCollectionPrayer` do take a `user` as an argument but it's unused inside the method

Comment: I just follow the video on youtube how to cound data https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5e_Tir8ot1c&ab_channel=ExtraServingsBTS, I just copied and added to count only for current user recorded data.

Comment: @Gwhyyy can you explained more details please. Sorry this is my first time learning flutter

Comment: oh sorry, I know now what it is, can you explain what you want to achieve in your code exactly

Comment: let say i have 2 users. So each user need to record their daily prayers. For example, user 1 want to record zohor prayer, so user 1 click the button zohor prayer and it will display showModalBootmSheet and inside the modal have three button which is button 'prayed on time', 'prayed late' & 'not prayed'. when the user click the button 'prayed on time' it will in to the database firebase. So my goals is i want to count the 'prayed on time' for current user only. Let's user 1 record 5 time 'prayed on time' so it will count only for user 1. If user 2 record, it will count for user 2 only @Gwhyyy

Comment: I understand, can you include also a screenshot of your firestore database so I can tell you what you will need to do

Comment: @Gwhyyy i have added the screenshot above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to show the on-time aggregate for each individual user, you need to somehow associate each document in `record_prayer` with each user. A common way to do that is to store the UID of that user in the document, for example in a `user` field.

Once you do that, you can get only the prayers for the current user by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) with a second `where` clause:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('record_prayer')
     .where('dailyPrayerStatus', isEqualTo: 'Prayed On Time')
     .where('user', isEqualTo: getuserId) // 
     .count()
     .get();
```

Comment: OMG!!! It work!!!! How can that be simple. Thank you thank you thank you <3